# is there a way to use the behavior trick for IE6 when the image is set inline?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, inline, behavior

```
<li><img alt="compra_segura" src="../../nImg/img_with_alpha.png" /></li>
```

is there a way to use the `behavior: url(/nJs/iepngfix.htc);` trick for IE6 (when the image has alpha) when the image is set inline and not in the stylesheet?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that it's all set up properly, you should just be able to add `img` to your "trigger the fix CSS":

```
img, div { behavior: url(iepngfix.htc) }
```

http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/